TAB key not handled in WinUI island from modal dialog
I have a Win32 app with UI written in WTL.
I need to display a modal dialog that has as content only a WinUI island.
I manged this, the WinUi content shows fine. The content consists of some TextBlocks and a row of buttons. Just like a MessageBox!
The problem is that pressing TAB key does not move focus between buttons.And no button has focus by default.
Actually no keyboard event fires. But buttons have keyboard accelerators and they work!
What should I do?

Does the Control.IsTabStop Property work for you? Or could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

See keyboard input and keyboard focus navigation.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT All buttons have IsTabStop="True" and an unique tab index.

@IInspectable I read the documentation and samples but still do not get it.
I am in a modal dialog and I do not know what message to handle and then call IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative2->PreTranslateMessage()

Just because you need a modal dialog doesn't mean you have to use the system's modal message loop. You can use either of the CreateDialog() functions and spin up your own modal message loop, or have your "normal" message loop process and dispatch messages. I'm not familiar with WTL so I don't know how much message processing customization it supports. All that said, keyboard navigation in WinUI (any version) is a hot mess.
